# Should I keep the predefined fields in schema.xml is Solr?

Tags: solr

I observed that, just after installing Solr, the file in which the fields and field types are defined (`schema.xml`) already contains some predefined fields that I will probably not use. I was about to remove them to add the ones that are useful to me, but I wanted to ask before if there is any concrete reason for keeping them. Or if I maybe should create a different `.xml` file for that. Are there any best practices for that or maybe it just doesn't matter? I just thought that it was suspicious that some fields were already defined there, but maybe they are just as examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not going to use a defined field type, there is no reason to keep the definition in schema.xml.

The reason it's there is to serve as an example for new users for the default schema used in the example core.

Comment: And this is applicable to both `field types` and `fields` as well, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no need for fields you're not going to use, or field types. The only exception is the `_version_` field if you're using SolrCloud (if there is a particular field of a particular type required by a module or extension you're using, the documentation for that module should tell you that)..